# how to get image in flutter through json

Tags: json, flutter

I want get images through JSON in flutter and I get data Successfully but I don't understand how to get images through dummy API . Kindly help for solve this issue as soon as possible. Thanks
llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

```
HOW TO GET IMAGE THROUGH DUMMY API?
Check this line in this code:
**backgroundImage: NetworkImage('${snapshot.data[i].thumbnail}'),** 

import 'dart:convert';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Ap2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Ap2({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Ap2State createState() => _Ap2State();
}

class _Ap2State extends State<Ap2> {

  getDetails()async{
    var users=[];
    
    var response = await http.get(Uri.https("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com","photos"));
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
     
    for(var i in jsonData){
      UserModel user = UserModel(i["id"],i['title'],['thumbnailUrl']);    
      users.add(user);
  
  }
    return (users);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getDetails(),
          builder: (context,snapshot){
            if(snapshot.data == null){
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Nothing in Api"),),);
            }
            else return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,i){
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("ID : ${snapshot.data[i].id}"),
                  subtitle: Text("Title : ${snapshot.data[i].title}"),
                  trailing: 
                  CircleAvatar(
                    **backgroundImage: NetworkImage('${snapshot.data[i].thumbnail}'),** 
                    ),
                );
              });
          })
    );
  }
}
class UserModel{
  var id;
  var title;
  final thumbnail;
 UserModel(this.id,this.title,this.thumbnail);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to put a part of the json that you are getting? What are you getting to represent the image is an url? If so, just the network itself. In flutter web you may have some color problems if the image is in another domain:  Image.network(_bloc.user!.photo!)